# How to use zoom and crop functionality using key listener in webview in JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx, webview, keylistener, keycode

i want to use zoom and crop in webview in JavaFx using key + for zoom out and - for zoomin and space for crop and F5 for save the crop image in my application im loading image from one webview to another 
 i had try this

```
final WebView img = new WebView();
     final WebEngine Img = img.getEngine();  
     final DoubleProperty zoomProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(200);
    img.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, (KeyEvent e) -> {
        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ADD || e.getCode() == KeyCode.EQUALS || e.getCode() == KeyCode.PLUS) {
            System.out.println("YES");
                zoomProperty.set(zoomProperty.get() * 1.1);
        }
        else if(e.getCode()== KeyCode.SUBTRACT||e.getCode() == KeyCode.MINUS ){
            System.out.println("YES");
            zoomProperty.set(zoomProperty.get() / 1.1);
        }
    });
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(img);
```

from this im able to detect the key but zoom is not working.First i have to change arrow pointer cursor to double headed arrow and then + key will zoomout and - key will zoomin.  please help as i had debug im able to detect the add and subtract key at the time of key pressed but i want to perform zoom but its not working in webview.

Answer (score 0):

i had solve my answer on my own as im just not adding the zoom property to webview.

```
img.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, (KeyEvent e) -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ADD || e.getCode() == KeyCode.EQUALS || e.getCode() == KeyCode.PLUS) {
                System.out.println("YES");
                     img.setZoom(img.getZoom() * 1.1);
            }
            else if(e.getCode()== KeyCode.SUBTRACT||e.getCode() == KeyCode.MINUS ){
                System.out.println("YES");
              img.setZoom(img.getZoom() / 1.1);
            }
        });
```